# Application works in Debug - Fails when compiled

Tags: c#

I have a situation I just don't understand.

I have a c# class library application that works perfectly when I step through it in debug mode within VS2017.

When I compile it in "Debug" mode and call it from a console app it fails when calling a https API endpoint and does not report any error.

This is how I am calling the "CreateOrder":

```
// send the order to DNAGenotek
DNAGenotek.Model.Order.CreateResponse.CreateOrderResponse orderResponse = await DNAGenotek.Orders.CreateOrder(DNAGenotekAPIKey, DNAGenotekOrder);
```

This is how I am calling the "CallAPIString" function:

```
public static async Task<Model.Order.CreateResponse.CreateOrderResponse> CreateOrder(string APIKey, Model.Order.Create.Order order)
    {
        // convert the object to a string
        string orderAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);

        // create the order
        string result = await Helpers.CallAPIString(APIKey, "https://sofia-stage.dnagenotek.com/api/v2/orders", "POST", orderAsString);

        DNAGenotek.Model.Order.CreateResponse.CreateOrderResponse orderResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Order.CreateResponse.CreateOrderResponse>(result);

        return orderResponse;
    }
```

I have attached to the running console .exe and stepped through and it fails on this line when doing a POST

```
WebResponse httpResponseGETDELETE = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

In the following code:

```
public static async Task<string> CallAPIString(string APIKey, string url, string method, string bodyContent = null)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Method = method;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + APIKey);

            switch (method)
            {
                case "GET":
                case "DELETE":
                    WebResponse httpResponseGETDELETE = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponseGETDELETE.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string result = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        return result;
                    }
                case "POST":
                case "PUT":
                case "PATCH":
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(bodyContent);
                        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
                        streamWriter.Close();

                        WebResponse httpResponsePOSTPUT = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

                        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponsePOSTPUT.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            string result = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    return "Method Not Found!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

It doesn't even bubble up to the catch line. It just closes the app.

When I watch the network traffic in Fiddler I can see it attempting to open the https connection but it then stalls.

This is what I see in Fiddler:

[image]

I am complete stumped how to get to the root cause without an error message?

**UPDATE**

I have now rewritten my code using the HttpClient and it now fails at the line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

in this code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + APIKey);
   StringContent content = new StringContent(bodyContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method - and thus, how do you expect to receive an error message?

Comment: I am running it by double click on the console.exe and then attaching the VS debugger and stepping through.

Comment: I think what @PieterWitvoet was implying was: how are you calling CallAPIString(), please could you show more of the calling code?

Comment: @peteski22 apologies. added code

Comment: No worries, I think the further up the stack we can see the easier it might be to help. e.g. you say you run this in VS (debugger) and it works, it's a class library, so what's kicking off calls to it? Where's the entry point etc. Sorry for all the comments.

Comment: If you want to see an error message you'll have to write it to the console or to a log file or something like that. If you're writing it to the console then you'll want to make sure it remains visible after the program has finished, for example by redirecting its output to a file or by launching the program from a command-line. If your program crashes then you should be able to find an entry in the Windows Event Log (often two, one which includes a stacktrace).

Answer (score 0):

OK - this was my fault.

In the console application I was using :

```
SyncEngine.Functions.Sync("APIKey1", "APIKey2");
```

When I should have been using:

```
SyncEngine.Functions.Sync("APIKey1", "APIKey2").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Sorry guys